# Stop Spring Batch from logging job parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are using Spring batch to automate some processes, and are passing in a number of parameters, some of which are sensitive passwords and can't be logged.

I have prevented these password from being logged by extending the `JobParameter` and `JobParameters` classes to create `SensitiveJobParameter` and `SensistiveJobParameters` classes respectively, which override the `toString()` and `getString()` methods respectively to allow the parameters to be returned correctly when required and logged as asterisks when required.

This allows me to mask the sensitive parameters with asterisks and seems to mostly work. However it looks like, and I'm still trawling through the logs to verify this is the case, if a job fails and is restarted the parameters are loaded from the database and aren't sanitized.

Is there a way in code/config to stop spring batch from logging it's parameters?

I know I could modify the slf4j config to stop the job launcher from logging, but that means that all someone has to do it change the logging config to log the passwords which I don't think is acceptable.

The parameters are specifically being logged by the `SimpleJobLauncher` [in this block of code:](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.java)

```
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    logger.info("Job: [" + job + "] launched with the following parameters: [" + jobParameters
                            + "]");
                    job.execute(jobExecution);
                    logger.info("Job: [" + job + "] completed with the following parameters: [" + jobParameters
                            + "] and the following status: [" + jobExecution.getStatus() + "]");
                }
                catch (Throwable t) {
                    logger.info("Job: [" + job
                            + "] failed unexpectedly and fatally with the following parameters: [" + jobParameters
                            + "]", t);
                    rethrow(t);
                }
            }

            private void rethrow(Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    throw (RuntimeException) t;
                }
                else if (t instanceof Error) {
                    throw (Error) t;
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException(t);
            }
        });
```

And if I can't find a better solution I can override the run method of the SimpleJob launcher to not have that logging statement, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Why not pass in a hashed version of the password instead? Or perhaps a path to a file which stores the password? Or use a properties file to store it rather than passing it via job parameter and then access it via `${password}`? Also, it is worth noting the parameters (and therefore the password) will end up being stored in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS`.

Comment: You can always configure your logging library to limit the output. In log4j, specify something like this:

    <logger name="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

Comment: Omar, did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.